# Pasar cualquier tipo de objeto y recuperarlo

Tags: java, primefaces

Estoy realizando un proyecto del que se trata de unas pantallas de inserción, eliminación y modificación de datos. 
Sé que podría poner un filtro (con un select desplegando todos los tipos de animales), pero por decisión superior tiene que ser así.

```
public class FiltroGato extends FiltroAnimal {
    public int id;
    public boolean esPersa;
    // getters & setters
}

public class FiltroPerro extends FiltroAnimal {
    public int id;
    public razaPeligrosa;
    // getters & setters
}

public class FiltroAnimal {
    public String nombre;
    public int edad;
    // getters & setters
}
```

Me gustaría poder ir almacenando el filtro, sin importar que éste sea de FiltroPerro o FiltroGato, poder hacer algo así:

```
FiltroGato filtro = new FiltroGato();
setFiltroAnimal(filtro);
```

¿Como se podría hacer?, he estado probando con los Java Generic, pero no logro conseguirlo.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Y que tipo de operaciones va a realizar el metodo `setFiltroAnimal`? Esto lo digo porque existen varias soluciones pero cada una son para casos especificos.

Comment: Realmente solo setear el tipo de filtro, es por hacerlo lo más reaprovechable posible. 
haré por ejemplo:
    FiltroGato filtro = new FiltroGato();
    filtro.setNombre("Kitty");
    filtro.esPersa(false);
    setFiltroAnimal(filtro);

Gracias, un saludo.